# How do I config an Email datasource in LoopBack for AWS SES email service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, loopbackjs

LoopBack [instructions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Email-connector.html) ask for an entry in the transports array of the `datasources.json` file.

AWS uses [nodemailer instructions](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/) ask for an object to be created.

But you cannot create a JS object in a json file.

Here is my `datasource.json` file so far. How do I configure the `awsEmail` datasource for AWS SES?

```
... 
  "awsEmail": {
    "name": "awsEmail",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "ses",
        "host": "aws.amazon.com",
        "secure": false,
        "port": 587,
        "tls": {
          "rejectUnauthorized": false
        },
        "auth": {
          "user": "my user name",
          "pass": "my password"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this with SMTP? The below works for me.

```
"awsEmail": {
  "name": "awsEmail",
  "connector": "mail",
  "defaultForType": "mail",
  "transports": [
    {
      "type": "SMTP",
      "host": "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "secure": true,
      "port": 465,
      "auth": {
        "user": "your smtp username",
        "pass": "your smtp password"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ses": {
    "name": "ses",
    "connector": "email",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "ses",
        "accessKeyId": "AWS accessKeyId",
        "secretAccessKey": "AWS secretAccessKey",
        "rateLimit": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

you must first create Ses user via console or cli and then use this user in your code. The following is python code I used for lambda execution which will send the file from s3 to my email. Please note enter the corret user and pwd

```
ses_user = "AKIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
ses_pwd = "AiKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxiiiiiiiiiiiixxxxxx"

def mail(fromadd,to, subject, text, attach):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = fromadd
   msg['To'] = to
   msg['Subject'] = subject
   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
   part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
   part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
   Encoders.encode_base64(part)
   part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
   msg.attach(part)
   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(ses_user, ses_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(fromadd, to, msg.as_string())
   # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
   mailServer.close()

date_fmt = strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())
#Give your file path
filepath ='/tmp/filename_' + date_fmt + '.csv'
#Give your filename
mail("sender_email","reciepient_email",filepath)
s3.Object('bucket', filename).put(Body=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```